# Python replace between two chars (no split function)

Tags: python, regex, string, validation, split

I currently investigate a problem that I want to replace something in a string.

For example. I have the following string:

'123.49, 19.30, 02\n'

I only want the first two numbers like '123.49, 19.30'. The split function is not possible, because a I have a lot of data and some with and some without the last number.

I tried something like this:

```
import re as regex

#result = regex.match(', (.*)\n', string)
result = re.search(', (.*)\\n', string)
print(result.group(1))
```

This is not working finde. Can someone help me?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is there always a comma after the second number?

Comment: Why do you use `import re as regex` and then `re.search`?

Comment: @intedgar no, when there is not a third number it looks like this: '123.51, 19.5\n'

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I already tried that. But it's not working. I think my given values are wrong? ', (.*)\\n'

Comment: That is wrong. You imported `re` as `regex` and then refer to `re`. Also, what are the requirements? Why do you try to match from a comma if you want to get the text before it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
reg=r'(\d+\.\d+), (\d+\.\d+).*'
if(re.search(reg, your_text)):
  match = re.search(reg, your_text)
  first_num = match.group(1)
  second_num = match.group(2)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Have a great day!

Comment: No problem, you too!

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, also adding the `^` sign at the beginning, making sure to always only take the first two.

```
import re
string = '123.49, 19.30, 02\n'
pattern = re.compile('^(\d*.?\d*), (\d*.?\d*)')

result = re.findall(pattern, string)
result
```

Output:
`[('123.49', '19.30')]`

Answer (score 0):

In the code you are using `import re as regex`. If you do that, you would have to use `regex.search` instead or re.search.

But in this case you can just use `re`.

If you use `, (.*)` you would capture all after the first occurrence of  `,` and you are not taking digits into account.

If you want the first 2 numbers as stated in the question `'123.49, 19.30'` separated by comma's you can match them without using capture groups:

```
\b\d+\.\d+,\s*\d+\.\d+\b
```

Or matching 1 or more repetitions preceded by a comma:

```
\b\d+\.\d+(?:,\s*\d+\.\d+)+\b
```

[regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/MOK9sY/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/gtD7Q8)

As [re.search](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.search) can also return None, you can first check if there is a result (no need to run re.search twice)

```
import re

regex = r"\b\d+\.\d+(?:,\s*\d+\.\d+)+\b"
s = "123.49, 19.30, 02"

match = re.search(regex, s)

if match:
    print(match.group())
```

Output

```
123.49, 19.30
```